# add event listener if does not exist in angular 5 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an angular hybrid application where part of the form is in angular 6 and the rest in AngularJS. This application is a single page application with content across ten tabs. I have replaced one tab content with angular 6. I have Implemented custom validation by adding an event listener as below.

```
 private continueBtn : any;
 private continueFunction : any;

this.continueBtn = document.querySelector('.continue'); 

constructor{
this.continueFunction = (e: Event) => {   
//do custom validation
}
this.continueBtn.addEventListener('click', this.continueFunction);
}
```

I have removed event listener as part of custom validation. Now when the user goes forward and comes back, as there are no listeners the user cannot go forward.
So I want to check for the condition --if(event listeners does not exist){ add event listener }

Comment: Why you have required to use AngularJS when you have latest Angular 6?

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is not to check for the listener. Instead add it new oninit and destroy it ondestroy. This will be safe and productive.